# Subprocess DPKG seems broken. How can I correct it?

Tags: debian, openmediavault

I require your assistance.

It seems that my sub-process dpkg is broken.
When I try

```
apt-get install -f
```

I get

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  openmediavault-iscsitarget
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 1 à enlever et 124 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 325 ko d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] o
(Lecture de la base de données... 43286 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de openmediavault-iscsitarget (3.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openmediavault-iscsitarget.postrm: 28: /var/lib/dpkg/info/openmediavault-iscsitarget.postrm: omv-mkconf: not found
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet openmediavault-iscsitarget (--remove) :
 installed openmediavault-iscsitarget package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 openmediavault-iscsitarget
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I try to remove openmediavault-iscsitarget, with

```
apt-get remove --purge openmediavault-iscsitarget
```

Or

```
apt remove openmediavault-iscsitarget
```

I still get the `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

A small trick, use `LANG=C` when looking for error or posting here, so we get English output (and you may Google better).

The error is in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/openmediavault-iscsitarget.postrm`, line 28.  Go to that line and comment out the line (adding a `#`). Sometime you may want to add as the first line whithout `#` an `exit 0`. This should be save on post removal script.

Next time try to avoid installing low quality packages. There is a package named `piuparts` which should help to find such problem before the developer upload a package. (And Debian does such test, among other tests).